# The meaning of "home question"

Tags: meaning

I have learned what "home truth" and "home thrust" means. But what is the meaning of "home question"? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You really should share here what "home truth" and "home thrust" means. (That would provide additonal context for the enthusiasts who want to do some detective work on your question.)

Comment: I think native speakers might not all understand *home truth*, *home thrust*, and *home question*.  I say this because I'm a native speaker and have no idea what any of them mean :-)

Answer (score 2):

All of these derive from figurative use of the adverb *home* in such phrases as *hit home* or *strike home*, meaning *hit the point aimed at*.

A weapon which strikes its target (or the person who directs it) is said to *hit home*. In the same way, a *home truth* or *home thrust* or *home question* is one which successfully ‘targets’ the person addressed and provokes the strong reaction which the speaker ‘aims at’.

Here's an example from a [19th-century sermon](http://www.spurgeon.org/sermons/0294.htm) addressed to moralists:

> I propose this morning, God helping me, to preach a very plain, faithful, and honest sermon; praying that it may **come home** to some of your hearts. You will find no smoothness about my speech but the very reverse. My sword may have a very mean hilt, but I do trust it shall have a very keen edge, and that it shall cut sharp, piercing to the dividing asunder of the joints and marrow. I shall first of all, put a **home question** [...] a question to ask of you, which perhaps you may not like, for you good moral people are very fond of your own righteousness. Let me ask you the question, “Is there not with you, even with you, some sin against the Lord your God?”

Answer (score 0):

Anything 'home' means your personal matter/attachment. As you said *Home Truth* is the bitter truth about yourself pointed out by someone or realized by you. In this sense, *Home Question* will be a direct question about your personal nature. Nevertheless, it's rarely used these days.

From the OED:

> **home truth**   *n*. a disagreeable fact about oneself, esp. as pointed out by another person.

Comment: Is this your assumption? Any reference pls...

Comment: Sure! @VijayaRagavan Here you go: http://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/87869